# How to add dynamic templates inside a layout template in django?

Tags: django

I want to {%include%} 8 different django templates inside 1 layout without making multiple layouts. 
My goal is to reduce the total number of .html files inside my template folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    {%load static%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'web/css/style.css'%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body style='margin: 0px;'>
    {%include 'web/header.html'%}
    {%include 'web/personal.html'%}
    {%include 'web/footer.html'%}    
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    template_name = 'web/index.html'
    p = personal.objects.all()
    return render(request,template_name)

def personal(request):
    template_name = 'web/personal.html'
    return render(request,template_name)

def blog(request):
    template_name = 'web/blog.html'
    return render(request,template_name)
```

So here are my templates
web/personal.html -> Some HTML
web/blog.html -> Some HTML
.
.
.
web/n.html -> Some HTML

I want these files to get included in my layout file dynamically
Thank You.

Comment: I think what you really want to do is template extending: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using different context to you base html will work:

views.py

```
def index(request):
    template_name = 'web/index.html'
    p = personal.objects.all()
    return render(request,template_name, context={"template_name":"index"})

def personal(request):
    template_name = 'web/personal.html'
    return render(request,template_name, context={"template_name":"personal"})

def blog(request):
    template_name = 'web/blog.html'
    return render(request,template_name, context={"template_name":"blog"})
```

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body style='margin: 0px;'>
    {% if template_name == "index" %}
        {%include 'web/header.html'%}
    {% elif template_name == "personal" %}
        {%include 'web/personal.html'%}
    {% elif template_name == "footer" %}
        {%include 'web/footer.html'%}
    {% endif %}    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked brother... Thank You so much you are smart, i didn't think of this way :D :D :D :D

Comment: your welcome. would you please mark as answered if you don't mind. thanks :)